# Increasing light intensity for logitech webcam

Tags: webcam, logitech, guvcview

I have a logitech webcam (C930 model).

It has an "activity light" that is supposed to adjust increase light in darker situations. It does not do so automatically.

I have attempted to use `xawtv` and `guvcview` to increase the intensity of this light, but neither programs seem to have such an option.

There is an option to adjust this intensity in the Logitech Webcam Software, but that is not Ubuntu supported.

Has anyone been able to increase the intensity of a logitech webcam light in Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't seem to understand "not supported". Logitech built their proprietary webcam protocol into their Windows software, and did not publish anything about their protocol.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. I should have said "Ubuntu is unable to support." Yet, many other webcam features are supported by both `xawtv` and `guvcview`, I was hoping for some package that could support lighting. (When on, the light is on very faintly so I had reason to ask.)